# Identify a small spider from southern Poland / eastern Europe

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

Can anyone identify this spider that I have just found in my home?

[image]
[image]

Details:

- location: [**Katowice, Upper Silesia, southern Poland, eastern Europe**](https://goo.gl/maps/nEhqACMc3XbtmQH58) (46.42 N, 17.78 E),
- size: **~3-3.5 cm** (from tip of one leg to tip of opposite leg) / **< 1 cm** (corpse lenght),
- date: **July 23th, 2020** (summer, approx. 10:30 am).

Comment: Are those ice crystals in the photo? I'm curious as to what surface the spider is on, seems almost like the windshield of a car.

Comment: No, it can't be ice, because it is a middle of summer here, in Poland right now. I found this spider in one of my rooms, captured it gently to some plastic pot and then move it to a windowsill beyond one of my windows, where it was released. These marks you spotted are microfractures in the windowsill itself. It seems, it was painted with using a fairly cheap paint, since in went into this condition in less then 10 years of a moderate weather conditions, we have here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a Barn Funnel Weaver (*Tegenaria domestica*), In Europe it is known as the [domestic house spider](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tegenaria_domestica).

Here's some photos of this species to prove the similarities:
[image]
[image]

What caught my eye in particular that made it more clear that it was this species was the color patterns on the abdomen and cephalothorax, the size you mentioned, the shape of the feelers as well as the location.

The slight difference in shade of color may be due to being a different variety of the species or simply because of the weather and habitat that the spider is in.

Comment: Thank you! As for the other differences you mention, I can't say anything specific as I am not a arachnology expert by no means. As for the size, I can be completely wrong, because when I came back to measure it, the spider was simply gone. But, I can see at Wikipedia: "_Their body/legs ratio is typically 50–60%, which accounts for a body size of 7.5–11.5 mm_" whic means, if I am not mistaken, that it has 2 cm at max. The one that I was observing certainly wasn't that small. I think it was more closer to 3 cm.

Comment: barn funnel weavers tend to have banded (striped) legs, while the specimen in question doesn't have banding and so it is likely Eratigena (a genus offshoot of Tegenaria) especially considering the leg length ratios. This is likely a 'giant house spider,' one of the Eratigena species.

Comment: @JimN You raise a fair point, I suggest you make a detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your spider is one of the **Giant House Spiders**. (Eratigena atrica complex). There are three species in this complex in Europe: E.atrica, E.duellica, E.saeva.

With the lack of banding in legs, it is not a barn funnel weaver as suggested in the other answer. ("Tegenaria spp. have banded legs, Eratigena spp. have plain legs" - [https://www.naturespot.org.uk/species/giant-house-spider#:~:text=The%20former%20genus%20Tegenaria%20has,the%20genitals%20of%20mature%20specimens](https://www.naturespot.org.uk/species/giant-house-spider#:%7E:text=The%20former%20genus%20Tegenaria%20has,the%20genitals%20of%20mature%20specimens). )

Some sources will equate the Eratigena and Tegenaria genuses with each other, while most separate them with a notable recent change of the *hobo spider* which used to be *Tegenaria agrestis* and now considered *Eratigena agrestis*. Taxonomy is ever-changing. A hobo spider would have two dark stripes running lengthwise on the carapace like the barn funnel weaver, which your specimen does not have. The Carapace marking of giant house spiders can have two dark stripes or a other patterns that look like radial lines emanating from the centre of the carapace.

Here is a photo of a giant house spider:
[image: E. atrica, (Observation © kevinindorset)]

They darken in colour as they grow in their shell/exoskeleton, and after molting, they are very light coloured (and vulnerable).

This second photo is one believed to be E. saeva:
[image: E. saeva (Observation © Paul Bowyer)]